# Can you change the default value of the nillable attribute in JAXB?

Tags: java, jaxb

I am refactoring some code to use JAXB and reflection to output code to the client, it is currently using an XMLWriter and manually creating the tags each time.

The problem I am having is that due to constraints on the client side, I need to have empty elements in the XML for any null fields in the java class.

While I realize this problem can be solved by adding `nillable=true` to each JAXB `XmlElement` annotation, that is not the most practical, as I have a lot of those annotations.

I was hoping to find a way to set `nillable=true` as a global attribute (or as the default value). This would also make it easier for future colleagues to work on it, as they won't need to remember that every annotation should include the `nillable` attribute.

I haven't found much besides descriptions of the default behavior. I find it surprising that no one else has posted a similar question in the past. From what I have found, it doesn't seem to me that there is any built-in support for making the default configurable.  Is this something that might be solved with a custom JAXB implementation or maybe a third party JAXB implementation?

Answer (score 1):

**Note:**  I'm the **[EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php)** lead and a member of the [**JAXB 2 (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

I have entered an enhancement request to have this behaviour added to EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy):

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/368547

**WORK AROUND**

As a work around if all your mapped String fields/properties are mapped to XML elements then the following XmlAdapter approach may work for you:

**NullStringAdapter**

This `XmlAdapter` will marshal instances of `String` as an object called `AdaptedString`.  `AdaptedString` contains the `String` value as well as a field mapped to the `xsi:nil` attribute.  In the `XmlAdapter` we will set the value of that field based on whether or not the `String` value is null.

```
package forum8841221;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.*;

public class NullStringAdapter extends XmlAdapter<NullStringAdapter.AdaptedString, String> {

    @Override
    public AdaptedString marshal(String v) throws Exception {
        AdaptedString adaptedString = new AdaptedString();
        if(null == v) {
            adaptedString.nil = true;
        }
        adaptedString.value = v;
        return adaptedString;
    }

    @Override
    public String unmarshal(AdaptedString v) throws Exception {
        return v.value;
    }

    public static class AdaptedString {

        @XmlAttribute(namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
        public Boolean nil;

        @XmlValue
        @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(VoidStringAdapter.class)
        public String value;

    }

    public static class VoidStringAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, String> {

        @Override
        public String marshal(String v) throws Exception {
            return v;
        }

        @Override
        public String unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
            return v;
        }

    }

}
```

**package-info**

We can register that we want this `XmlAdapter` to apply to all the mapped `String` fields/properties on this package by registering the `XmlAdapter` at the package level.

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=NullStringAdapter.class, type=String.class)
@XmlSchema(xmlns={@XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", prefix = "xsi")})
package forum8841221;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
```

**Root**

Below is the domain class I have used for this example.  It has several String properties, one of them is annotated with @XmlElement(nillable=true)

```
package forum8841221;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Root {

    private String a;
    private String b;
    private String c;
    private String d;

    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(String b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public String getC() {
        return c;
    }

    public void setC(String c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    @XmlElement(nillable=true)
    public String getD() {
        return d;
    }

    public void setD(String d) {
        this.d = d;
    }

}
```

**Demo**

```
package forum8841221;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        Root root = new Root();
        root.setB("B");

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <a xsi:nil="true"/>
   <b>B</b>
   <c xsi:nil="true"/>
   <d xsi:nil="true"/>
</root>
```